# How to pad an integer so that n characters are displayed in the resulting string?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, integer, padding

Let's say I have an integer i, and want to display n characters total when I output the integer as a string (padding the string with leading zeros).

For example:

```
i = 10, n = 2 ==> 10
i = 10, n = 3 ==> 010
i = 5,  n = 2 ==> 05
i = 5,  n = 3 ==> 005
```

Comment: @Grant Winney I would argue that it's not exactly a duplicate, since the question linked doesn't cover the padding being of variable length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i.ToString(string.Format("D{0}", n));
```